# 'cat' command in ansible playbook won't append file

Tags: linux, file, ansible, append

I am new to ansible and am currently trying to create a simple playbook that installs ssmtp, sends a message (with the body being the contents of a given file) then erases ssmtp again. I have /tmp/message.txt where the 'from', 'to' and other details are stored and the /tmp/file.txt which just has two rows of 12345678.

The goal is to have an email sent out that has the subject 'test' and the body just being the two rows of the numbers. What I can't understand though is why the "cat /tmp/file.txt >> /tmp/message.txt" does not append the contents of file.txt to message.txt This works fine when just run as a command in the terminal or when the same commands are used in a bash script. I get that this is probably an easy oversight, but after trying several other commands I can't seem to reach a solution. Playbook text is below:

```
---
 - name: install ssmtp and send email
   hosts: the_server_itself
   become: true
   become_user: root
   tasks:
     - name: "install ssmtp"
       yum: 
         name: ssmtp 
         state: latest
         
     - name: "add mail provider"
       shell:
         cmd: echo -e "mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587\n" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
     - name: "add auth settings"
       shell:
         cmd: echo -e "UseSTARTTLS=Yes \nAuthUser=<username> \nAuthPass=<password> \nAuthMethod=LOGIN \n" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
         
     - name: "send out email"
       shell:
        cmd: chfn -f "<sender name>" root
     - name: "create message file"
       file:
        path: /tmp/message.txt
        state: touch
     - name: "append message file" 
       shell: 
         cmd: 'echo -e "From: <sender@mail.provider>\nSubject: Test\n\n" > /tmp/message.txt'
     - name: "add file to  message"
       shell: 
         cmd: 'cat /tmp/file.txt >> /tmp/message.txt'
       shell: 
         cmd: ssmtp  <recipient@mail.provider> < /tmp/message.txt
         
     - name: "erase ssmtp"
       yum:
         name: ssmtp
         state: removed
     - name: "erase message.txt"
       file:
         path: /tmp/message.txt
         state: absent
...
```

And thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
     - name: "add file to  message"
       shell: 
         cmd: 'cat /tmp/file.txt >> /tmp/message.txt'
       shell: 
         cmd: ssmtp  <recipient@mail.provider> < /tmp/message.txt
```

These are meant to be separate list entries.  You should write like this, different shell commands with different names:

```
     - name: "add file to  message"
       shell: 
         cmd: 'cat /tmp/file.txt >> /tmp/message.txt'
     - name: send with ssmtp
       shell: 
         cmd: ssmtp  <recipient@mail.provider> < /tmp/message.txt
```